Closed form numeric solutions for the harmonic oscillator via explicit and implicit Euler method
I am currently trying to apply the explicit and implicit Euler method to the harmonic oscillator
$y'' + y = 0, y(0)=0, y'(0)=1$.
I have reduced the ODE to first order via
$y'=v, v'=-y, y(0)=0, v(0)=1$.
Furthermore, I have shown the following recursion formulas for the explicit Euler method with step size h:
$y_{k+2}=2y_{k+1}-(1+h^2)y_k$
And for the implicit Euler method with step size h:
$(1+h^2)y_{k+2}=2y_{k+1}-y_k$.
I am now trying to find closed form solutions for both Euler methods. For the explicit Euler method I realized that
$2y_{k-1}=2(2y_{k-2}-\underline{(1+h^2)y_{k-3}})$
and
$(1+h^2)y_{k-2}=(1+h^2)(\underline{2y_{k-3}}-(1+h^2)y_{k-4})$
The underlined terms cancel out. So the mixed terms always cancel out, only leaving the "pure" terms. Unfortunately this leads me to a pretty  wonky solution where I have to distinguish if k is even or odd.
For k even I get
$y_k= 2^{k-1}y_1+(1+h^2)^{\frac{k}{2}}y_0$.
And for k odd I get
$y_k= 2^{k-1}y_1+(1+h^2)^{\frac{k-1}{2}}y_1$.
Is this the correct approach? Or did I miss a better one? Can I try something similar for the implicit version?

So, for the explicit Euler method, solving the recursion
$$
y_{k+2}-2 y_{k+1} +(1+h^2)y_k = 0,
$$
using the standard characteristic polynomial approach for linear difference equations, leads to
$$
y_k = c_1 \left(\sqrt{1+h^2}\right)^k \cos\left(k \arcsin\left(\frac{h}{\sqrt{1+h^2}} \right)\right)+ c_2 \left(\sqrt{1+h^2}\right)^k \sin\left(k \arcsin\left(\frac{h}{\sqrt{1+h^2}} \right)\right)
$$
Taking into account that $y_0=0, \quad y_1 = h $, we get $c_1=0, c_2=1$ and, consequently, that
$$y_k = 
\left(\sqrt{1+h^2}\right)^k \sin\left(k \arcsin\left(\frac{h}{\sqrt{1+h^2}} \right)\right).
$$
If you repeat the same procedure for the other difference equation (implicit Euler), you get
$$
y_k = c_1\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{1+h^2}\right)^k}\cos\left(k \arcsin\left( \frac{h}{\sqrt{1+h^2}} \right)\right) +
c_2\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{1+h^2}\right)^k}\sin\left(k \arcsin\left( \frac{h}{\sqrt{1+h^2}} \right)\right),
$$
where $c_1=0$ and $c_2=1+h^2$.
Note: For the first difference equation (explicit Euler), the characteristic polynomial is given by $p(\lambda)=\lambda^2-2 \lambda + (1+h^2)$, which has complex roots $\lambda = 1 \pm i h = \rho e^{i \theta}$. Hence, the general solution of the difference equation is given by
$$
y_k = c_1 \rho^k \cos (k \theta) + c_2 \rho^k \sin (k \theta),
$$
where $\rho = |1\pm i h| = \sqrt{1+h^2}$, $\sin \theta = \frac{h}{\sqrt{1+h^2}}$, and $c_1, c_2$ are computed from the initial conditions.
None of the methods recovers the periodic nature of the exact solution, which is wrongly amplified or damped. In the pictures below you can see the behavior when $h = 0.1$.



Thanks, could you explain what you mean by "standard characteristic polynomial approach"? Do you formulate the difference equation as a matrix equation?

When you have a linear difference equation of the form $y_{k+2} + a y_{k+1} + b y_k =0$, which has the characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)= \lambda^2+ a \lambda + b$, you can determine the general solution based on the roots of $p(\lambda)$. In the first example the roots are $1 \pm i h = \sqrt{1+h^2} e^{i \frac{h}{\sqrt{1+h^2}}}$

Thanks a lot! I think I understand it now.
